# GraphQL mutation structure

Tags: graphql

I am trying to create a Node.js graphql server in Typescript. I am using Express and express-graphql. I have some issues with how to structure my mutation when I want to create a new User.

My goal is to be able to use a mutation like this:

```
mutation {
  user {
    create(
      data: {
        name: "Foo Bar"        
      }
    ) {
      id,
      name
    }    
  }
}
```

Here is my User types:

```
import {
  GraphQLObjectType,
  GraphQLNonNull,
  GraphQLBoolean,
  GraphQLString,
  GraphQLInputObjectType
} from 'graphql';

export const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'User',
  description: 'A user of the application',
  fields: () => ({
    id: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString),
      description: 'The id of the user',
    },
    name: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString),
      description: 'The name of the user',
    }
  })
});

export const UserInputType = new GraphQLInputObjectType({
  name: 'UserInputType',
  description: 'User payload definition',
  fields: () => ({
    name: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) }
  })
});
```

Here is my attempt at defining the mutation on the server:

```
// ../user/user-mutations.ts

export const userMutations = {
  user: {
    type: new GraphQLObjectType({
      name: 'CreateUser',
      fields: {
        create: {
          type: UserType,
          args: {
            data: {
              type: new GraphQLNonNull(UserInputType),
            }
          },
          resolve: async (rootValue, { data }) => {
            return Object.assign(data, {
              id: '123'
            });
          }
        }
      }
    })
  }
};
```

My errors/output:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot convert undefined or null to object",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 36,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "user"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "user": null
  }
}
```

Question 1: Is this way of structuring a mutation not optimal? Should I rather do something like:

```
mutation {
  createUser(
    name: "Foo Bar"
  ) {
    id,
    name
  }
}
```

Question 2: If my first structure is fine, how can I fix the structure of my mutation on the server to create my user and return the values requested?

**Edit:** Here is my top level schema:

```
import { userQueries } from '../user/user-queries';

export const queries = {
  ...userQueries
};

import { userMutations } from '../user/user-mutations';

export const mutations = {
  ...userMutations
};


const rootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'RootQuery',
  fields: queries
});

const rootMutation = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'RootMutation',
  fields: mutations
});

export const schema = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: rootQuery,
  mutation: rootMutation
});
```

Comment: Please modify your question to include the schema for your top-level Mutation object.

Comment: I added my top level schema, hope that helps!

Comment: I can effectively copy and paste your code into an empty project and it works fine with one small modification -- you need to add a resolve function for the `CreateUser` type that returns an empty object. Without it, the `create` resolver is never triggered and user just returns null. I can't really think of how to reproduce the error you're seeing though.